# Get another image after download

Tags: c#, download

I want to download some product image in here:
"http://www.kelkoo.no/c-100334923-babyutstyr/merke/brio"
I use:

```
 WebClient webClient = new WebClient(); 
 string photourl = "http://r.kelkoo.com/r/no/12085413/100334923/162/162/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.jollyroom.no%2Fmedia%2Fcatalog%2Fproduct%2Fcache%2F5%2Fimage%2F200x200%2F9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95%2F1%2F3%2F138489_1.jpg/R8i4cK4LKSF.G4h1Vyz5UptpU1E3B6l5vcwIb_iyNHQ-";
 webClient.DownloadFile(photourl, Application.StartupPath + @"\image\" +i.ToString()   +".jpeg");
```

I get another one, a blank image!
Hope to be help by you.

Comment: i'm using your Example Code , it's can execute and the image it's not blank , i think it's you download too many times And the server is block your ip,And do you have try use physics path Like C:\A.jpg ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**Update 1 For Web Application** :

```
 using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            string photourl = "http://r.kelkoo.com/r/no/12085413/100334923/162/162/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.jollyroom.no%2Fmedia%2Fcatalog%2Fproduct%2Fcache%2F5%2Fimage%2F200x200%2F9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95%2F1%2F3%2F138489_1.jpg/R8i4cK4LKSF.G4h1Vyz5UptpU1E3B6l5vcwIb_iyNHQ-";
            webClient.DownloadFile(photourl, Server.MapPath(@"\image\" +i.ToString()   +".jpeg"));
        }
```

**Result :**

[image]

**Update 2 For Windows Application**

```
 using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                string photourl = "http://r.kelkoo.com/r/no/12085413/100334923/162/162/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.jollyroom.no%2Fmedia%2Fcatalog%2Fproduct%2Fcache%2F5%2Fimage%2F200x200%2F9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95%2F1%2F3%2F138489_1.jpg/R8i4cK4LKSF.G4h1Vyz5UptpU1E3B6l5vcwIb_iyNHQ-";
                webClient.DownloadFile(photourl, Application.StartupPath + i.ToString() + ".jpeg");
    }
```

**Result :**

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, I tried it, but it doesn't solve my problem

Comment: What was the main problem?

Comment: I want a image like here:http://r.kelkoo.com/r/no/12085413/100334923/162/162/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.jollyroom.no%2Fmedia%2Fcatalog%2Fproduct%2Fcache%2F5%2Fimage%2F200x200%2F9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95%2F1%2F3%2F138489_1.jpg/R8i4cK4LKSF.G4h1Vyz5UptpU1E3B6l5vcwIb_iyNHQ-  but I receive like   http://r.kelkoo.com/r/no/11773713/100334923/162/162/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gobaby.no%2Fmedia%2Fcatalog%2Fproduct%2Fcache%2F2%2Fimage%2F265x%2F9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95%2Fc%2Fl%2Fclown_1_1.jpg/GNSFkSE_wxJbq.FoXKvfVIhDbNtOsgcbly6DfMk1AQA-

Comment: @jasmine I think this may be threw error in Application.StartupPath. Please check my update answer now. It's working well in my local machine

Comment: I got unexpected result image. I got a blank image, not the image I see on the web.

Comment: Do you got the image with violet color, not a blank?  My code is on windows form, not web form.

Comment: Yes Not a blank. It's violet  color same image

Comment: @jasmine I have found out your problem , That is the Path Problem please see my final answer Update 2

Comment: Many thanks, I used your "Update 2" but I still get blank image. It's strange! I don't what's happening with my code and my computer!